# can someone please point me in the right direction

Tags: java, loops

I am working on a project that will take a random set of numbers from user entry into a console, add the numbers for a sum and display the numbers entered as well as the sum of the numbers in a space delimited format, so if the numbers entered are 1234 it will out put 1 2 3 4 = 10

the working code I have is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MurphyCounter
{
   static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
   public static void main(String[] args)
      {
      int mstop;                                                                  
      int number;                                                                 
      int sum;                                                                    
      int mcounter;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print(" Now many numbers am I adding? ");                      
                mstop = console.nextInt();                                        
                System.out.println();                                           
                sum = 0;                                                          
                mcounter = 0;

        System.out.println(" Please provide  " + mstop
                + " numbers.");                                                   
            while (mcounter < mstop)                                               
            {
                number = console.nextInt();                                     
                sum = sum + number;                                             
                mcounter++;                                                      
            }                                                                     
        System.out.printf("The sum of these %s " +
                "numbers = %d%n", mstop, sum);
        System.out.println();                                                     
            if (mcounter != 0)                                                     
        System.out.printf("Thank you for your input" );                           
            else
```

I am hitting a wall and have been for the better part of a week now...
Please help!

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: I can't see any problem here ... apart from the fact that you haven't finished writing the code.  (And your indentation is a mess.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't store the input numbers, if you only want to print them in the end it is sufficient to store them in a string `numbers += " " + Integer.toString(number);`.
The whole main would then look something like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int mstop;
    int number;
    int sum;
    int mcounter;
    String numbers = "";

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print(" Now many numbers am I adding? ");
    mstop = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    sum = 0;
    mcounter = 0;

    System.out.println(" Please provide  " + mstop + " numbers.");
    while (mcounter < mstop) {
        number = console.nextInt();
        sum = sum + number;
        numbers += " " + Integer.toString(number);
        mcounter++;
    }
    System.out.print("The sum of these " + mstop + " numbers:" + numbers
            + " = " + sum);
    System.out.println();
    if (mcounter != 0) {
        System.out.printf("Thank you for your input");
    }
}
```

Comment: oh my god! thank you so much, I was trying to figure that out for what seems like a month of sunday's!

Comment: Glad I could help you, if it solved your problem please accept my answer. Just to mention it, your example is missing the last view lines to close the function and class.